# OpenGL multiple frambuffers VS re-bind the color attachment with only one framebuffer

Tags: opengl

If we want to get the previous frame texture every frame, we can use two FBO, and do something like that:

```
uint fbos[2];
uint textures[2];

// attach...
for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    // ...
    glBindFrameBuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbos[i]);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[i]);

    // ...
}

// every frame

int i = frame % 2;
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbos[i]);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[1-i]);
draw();
```

But we can also use only one FBO :

```
// every frame

GLuint frambuffer; glGenFramebuffers(1, &framebuffer);

// init...
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[i]);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[1-i]);
draw();

glDeleteFramebuffers(1, &framebuffer);
```

It is simpler to use the second method as when we create a new post-effect, we don't have to create a new FBO. So is it advisable to do so performance-wise?

**TL; DR; Is it advisable to call `glFramebufferTexture2D()` every frame and create an FBO every frame?**

Comment: You’d have to run benchmarks to be sure, but I’m willing to bet that creating new framebuffers each frame is not going to be great for performance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the previous frame data than using a pixel buffer object would be a very fast solution.

Create two pixel buffer objects and get the data in this manner.

```
glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
w_writeIndex = (w_writeIndex + 1) % 2;
w_readIndex = (w_readIndex + 1) % 2;
glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, w_pbo[w_writeIndex]);
// copy from framebuffer to PBO asynchronously. it will be ready in the NEXT frame
glReadPixels(0, 0, SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, nullptr);
// now read other PBO which should be already in CPU memory
glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, w_pbo[w_readIndex]);
unsigned char* previousFrameData = (unsigned char*)glMapBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, GL_READ_ONLY);
```